# Restrict certain mods to certain worlds

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have lots of mods installed on my Minecraft client. How can I make certain mods only work in certain worlds?

For example, how can I make the train mod work only for one of my worlds not the others and have BuildCraft work for all my worlds except the one with the train mod?

Comment: That would not be possible, or at least a hell of a lot of work.

Comment: I get what you are trying to ask, but could you maybe make it a bit clearer for others who might want to answer this question? Maybe edit your question?

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend downloading and trying [Magic Lancher](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/939149-launcher-magic-launcher-125-mods-options-profiles-news/). You can easily enable and disable mods or even set different configurations.

For example:

Configuration 1 = Train mod on and build craft off.

Configuration 2 = Train mod off and build craft on.

You can easily change between configurations before you launch the game.